# Is it possible to "concatenate" blocks from child and parent Tornado templates?

Tags: python, templates, tornado

I have a few templates like this:

base.html

```html
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
{% block scripts %}
{% end %}
```

blog-base.html

```html
{% extends base.html %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="/js/blog-base.js"></script>
{% end %}
```

blog-article.html

```html
{% extends blog-base.html %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="/js/blog-article.js"></script>
{% end %}
```

I would like to have all three scripts included in the final product, but of course the above code won't do that, instead opting to replace blog-base.html's `script` block with the one in blog-article.html. Is there any way, besides setting up a separate block name, to make this work? I imagined something like this for blog-article.html

```html
{% extends base.html %}
{% block scripts %}
    <script src="/js/blog-base.js"></script>
    {% render-block scripts %}
    {% end %}
{% end %}
```

to have it both render the child template's `scripts` block *and* define a block for the parent `base.html` to use, but I have my doubts that such a thing exists.

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible (and difficult to implement with the way Tornado templates currently work).  For the particular case of adding script tags you might be able to use UIModules (which have special support for adding scripts or css links to the current page) instead of extending a base template.